# logging the audio amplitutde in html5 audio api and javascript with console.log()

Tags: javascript, html, audio

If you check out this jsbin, you will notice that the circle beats and pulses according to the highest points of the audio wavelength amplitude.

http://jsbin.com/ovesiv/4/edit

I am trying to log this audio amplitude to the console, but it's quite confusing.  Do you use console.log(buffer)?  console.log(amp)?  or something else all together?  Also, where do you type that line.

My end goal is to have a widget that has 5 different colors.  One color for very low (almost silence), one color for low, one fore medium, one for high, and one for very high.

So, if I was going to write an if statement that changed the color of the circle for these 5 levels of amplitude, how would I do that?

Thanks for your help!  It's a new api, so the questions are not readily available on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Logging**

Just put `console.log(amp);` right before `circle.setAttribute(...)`.

**2. Colors**

Create a lookup table (outside `processAudio`):

```
var colorLUT = [
        "rgb(255,   0,   0)", // Very low
        "rgb(255, 255,   0)", // Low
        "rgb(  0, 255,   0)", // Medium
        "rgb(  0, 255, 255)", // High
        "rgb(  0,   0, 255)"  // Very high
    ];
```

...and choose color according to the current amplitude:

```
var color = 
    amp < 0.2 ? colorLUT[0] :
    amp < 0.4 ? colorLUT[1] :
    amp < 0.6 ? colorLUT[2] :
    amp < 0.8 ? colorLUT[3] :
                colorLUT[4];
```